# bing maps on WP7 restrict the viewport

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, bing-maps

Im using the Bing Maps control on my Windows Phone 7 app, I need to make sure the user doesnt go outside a pre-defined area, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a handler that listens to the viewchangeend event, which fires after the map view changes (i.e. after every pan/zoom action) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.map_events.aspx.

When the viewchangeend event fires, retrieve the bounds of the new map view via the BoundingRectangle property (or just get the centrepoint of the map using the Center property) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.map_properties.aspx

Then, check whether the new map view lies within your pre-defined area. If it doesn't, set the map back to the previous view or adjust it so that it lies in range again using the SetView() method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.core.mapcore.setview.aspx.

Comment: sounds good, thanks Alastair, I was going to do this but I thought perhaps there was a better cleaner way. But this is ok I guess.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a static image of a map instead of a map control its self.

The Bing Maps RESTful API has a static imagery endpoint - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701721.aspx

Comment: i already have the mapping info, i just need to restrict the viewport

Comment: doesn't setting the map area and map size give you what you want?

Comment: I don't think Mark wants a static map that restricts any interactivity whatsoever, but a map that can be panned/zoomed only within a pre-defined area.